# Proof of the escape to horizontal infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

**Escape to horizontal infinity:** Let $R$ be the real line with Lebesgue measure, and let $f_n := 1_{[n,n+1]}$. Then $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f:=0$, but $\int_R f_n(x)dx=1$ doesn't converge to $\int_R f(x)dx=0$.

My attempt to prove it:

1) Pointwise convergence: $\forall x, \forall\epsilon>0$ there is N, such that $\forall n>N$
$$
|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \epsilon
$$
In case of $f_n := 1_{[n,n+1]}$ given some $x$ we can always increase $n$ so $x$ isn't in the interval $[n,n+1]$
$$
|f_n(x) - 0| \leq \epsilon
$$
A as result $f_n\rightarrow f:= 0$ pointwise

2) Convergence in $L^1$ norm: a sequence of functions $f_n$ converges to $f$ if $\int_R |f_n-f|\rightarrow 0$

$$
|\int f_n-\int f|=|\int(f_n-f)| \leq \int |f_n-f| \rightarrow 0
$$

$\int_R f_n = 1$, so $\int_R f\rightarrow1$ and therefore $f_n\nrightarrow f:=0$ in $L^1$-norm

**Questions:**

Is my proof correct and if not what are the problems with it?

Can't understand intuitively how a pointwise convergence could happen if functions ($f:=0$ and $f_n := 1_{[n,n+1]}$) are different.

Comment: Your proof is correct. For the last question: what do you mean by " functions are different"?

Comment: Crostul, thank you! I meant $f:=0$ and $f_n := 1_{[n,n+1]}$

Comment: "pointwise convergence" means point by point. Now, for every point $x$ you have the sequence $f_n(x)$: this sequence is eventually $0$, so "at that point" you have convergence to $0$.